# What is the prefered way to split a Birt rtpdesign?

Tags: reporting, birt

We use BIRT to generate some really complex documents (multiple big tables, nested grids, large data sets, many visibility settings). While growing the template we observed steady performance degradation and today we reached the point, were we can't maintain this template anymore. We tried to extract parts of the Template to library files, this improved performance while editing the report items, but not when editing the main template.

Is there a better way to split a BIRT template? Or are their any other suggestions for improving the editing performance?

Comment: Is there a reason you can not use multiple reports/templates?

Comment: @JamesJenkins: We have to generate continuous page numbers, table of contents etc.. If this is possible to arrange this and to concatenate multiple output formats (at least PDF, HTML, DOCX), then we might use multiple reports/templates. But I don't think that it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment, that you main reason for such a large report is

> to generate continuous page numbers

I don't have the knowledge about your set up, to give you a complete solution, but I would look towards breaking it up into several reports and passing the page number to the next report. One way would to have a link at the bottom of the first report, with the starting page number of the next report as an parameter value.  You link would look something like this.

MyReportLivesHere.com/run?_*report=Report1.rptdesign&page=15&*_format=pdf

You may or may not be able to have the link automatically launched.

You would probably need run the table of contents last, and physically move it from the bottom of the report printing or just leave it as the last entry.

Comment: This seems to be a feasible solution. But it needs a lot manual work. At least we have to build three different routines to concatenate documents and we have to orchestrate this process. This negates many of the advantages of Birt. But maybe there is no better solution.

Comment: @gregor My answer is based on experience with the free version of BIRT, the commercial version may have attributes to simplify a solution for you.  If you are running the commercial version contact your vendor.